# CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName doesn't work in "onOpen" trigger function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have created a function in my Google Spreadsheet to access to my calendar and automatically fill in the spreadsheet.

This function runs fine, but if I put `mycal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName();`
in the `onOpen` function it stops here. If I run it manually, the `onOpen` executes perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trigger (like `onOpen()`) cannot do anything that requires user authentication.
Read [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple).

It works when you run it manually in the script editor, because it's not executing in response to a trigger at that time.